# how to drop rows if a variale is less than x, in sql

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, kaggle

I have the following query code

```
query = """
with double_entry_book as (
    SELECT to_address as address, value as value
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    WHERE to_address is not null
    AND block_timestamp < '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND status = 1
    AND (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
    union all
    -- credits
    SELECT from_address as address, -value as value
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.traces`
    WHERE from_address is not null
    AND block_timestamp < '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND status = 1
    AND (call_type not in ('delegatecall', 'callcode', 'staticcall') or call_type is null)
    union all
)
SELECT address, 
sum(value) / 1000000000000000000 as balance 
from double_entry_book
group by address
order by balance desc
LIMIT 15000000
"""
```

In the last part, I want to drop rows where "balance" is less than, let's say, 0.02 and then group, order, etc. I imagine this should be a simple code. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: 1) `value as value` is redundant and in `-value as value`, `-value` is not a valid  identifier name. 2) From here [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): "The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified."  So you will not be able to do this.

Comment: is there a way to LIMIT not the first n rows but middle rows? The reason why I am asking this, the whole table has arnd 76m rows, due to memory limit,  i can only retrieve 15m, I wonder if i can get the rows between 15m and 30m?

Comment: See [Offset/Limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

Comment: `Select [columns] from table_name offset 15000000`

Answer (score 1):

We can delete on a CTE and use `returning` to get the id's of the rows being deleted, but they still exist until the transaction is comitted.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t (
>     id serial,
>     variale int);
> insert into t (variale) values
> (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

5 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with del as
> (delete from t 
> where variale < 3
> returning id)
> select 
>   t.id,
>   t.variale,
>   del.id ids_being_deleted
> from t
> left join del
> on t.id = del.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | variale | ids_being_deleted
> -: | ------: | ----------------:
>  1 |       1 |                 1
>  2 |       2 |                 2
>  3 |       3 |              null
>  4 |       4 |              null
>  5 |       5 |              null
> ```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | variale
> -: | ------:
>  3 |       3
>  4 |       4
>  5 |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c4f2d1ce8d33c313cba8c996c890584e)*